# Classic ASP, MySQL or ODBC UTF8 encoding

Tags: mysql, utf-8, asp-classic, character-encoding, odbc

I have a website hosted with GoDaddy, including MySQL database on the back end. The site is a Slovenian site, so special characters are used.

The website is built in classic ASP and I have all the pages created in Notepad++ where utf-8 encoding is used. At the top of every page I also have Session.CodePage=65001, Session.LCID=1060 and Response.Charset="utf-8". MySQL db and all the tables are also utf8 encoded.

If I look at the data directly in db through Workbench interface, everything is ok, including some special Slovenian characters I use, like: č

If I go to my website, the Slovenian characters are also printed just fine, including č

The only problem is, that on the same page, data retrived from MySQL is not coded correctly, so letter č becommes ?

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

First I thought it is the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver, which I use to connect to db. I have tried adding charset=utf8 to the connection string, but didn't work. I have also tried adding charset=ucs2 to the connection string, which is a tip I found on another website, but it didn't help either. GoDaddy is not supporting MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver, which could be a solution.

I am running out of options, so please help.

Comment: Are your pages themselves saved in UTF-8 format, or have you just used meta tags to set the charset.  

In other words, when you open a page in Notepad and select Save As from the File menu.  What is the Endcoding drop down set to?  If it is "ANSI" then change it to "UTF-8"

Comment: Yes, pages are saved in UTF8. I use Notepad++.

Comment: I think you're probably right about the driver.  There's a site I'm working on which is gradually being converted from Classic to .net.  A while back I Google translated the About Us page into Russian and pasted it into the database to see if it would cope with cyrillic.  It works fine if I use .net, but I've just to pull the same record with Classic and I get what you get.  It uses the 3.51 driver for classic.  Links to both pages here http://www.clubdanceholidays.co.uk/AboutUs.aspx?language=Russian http://www.clubdanceholidays.co.uk/aboutusru.asp

Comment: And switching to the 5.1 driver does solve the problem for me.  Maybe you need to find another Web host.  Thank's for the question - I've learned something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a chance for Slovenian letters according to this [mapping](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/bestfit1252.txt) and an excerpt from [Windows-1252 wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252):

> According to the information on Microsoft's and the Unicode Consortium's websites,
> positions 81, 8D, 8F, 90, and 9D are unused; however, the Windows API
> [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886760.aspx) maps these to the corresponding [C1 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).
>
> The euro character at position 80 was not present in earlier versions of this code page,
> nor were the S, s, Z, and z with caron (háček).

Here's the things to do:

1. Use UTF-8 (without BOM) encoded files against the possibility of contain hard-coded text. (✔ already done)
2. Specify UTF-8 for response charset with ASP on server-side or with meta tags on client-side. (✔ already done)
3. Tell the MySQL Server your commands are in charset utf-8, and you expect utf-8 encoded result sets. Add an initial statement to the connection string : `...;stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8';...`
4. Set the Response.CodePage to 1252.

I've tested the following script and it works like a charm.

**DDL:** [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/c2c35/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/c3397/1)

**ASP:**

```vb
<%@Language=VBScript%>
<% 
Option Explicit

Response.CodePage = 1252
Response.LCID = 1060
Response.Charset = "utf-8"

Const adCmdText = 1, adVarChar = 200, adParamInput = 1, adLockOptimistic = 3

Dim Connection
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
    Connection.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDb;User=myUsr;Password=myPwd;stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8';"
    
If Request.Form("name").Count = 1 And Len(Request.Form("name")) Then 'add new
    Dim rsAdd
    Set rsAdd = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
        rsAdd.Open "names", Connection, ,adLockOptimistic
        rsAdd.AddNew
        rsAdd("name").Value = Left(Request.Form("name"), 255)
        rsAdd.Update
        rsAdd.Close
    Set rsAdd = Nothing
End If

Dim Command
Set Command = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Command")
    Command.CommandType = adCmdText
    Command.CommandText = "Select name From `names` Order By id Desc"
    
    If Request.QueryString("name").Count = 1 And Len(Request.QueryString("name")) Then
        Command.CommandText = "Select name From `names` Where name = ? Order By id Desc"
        Command.Parameters.Append Command.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Left(Request.QueryString("name"), 255))
    End If
    
    Set Command.ActiveConnection = Connection
    With Command.Execute
        While Not .Eof
            Response.Write "<a href=""?name=" & .Fields("name").Value & """>" & .Fields("name").Value & "</a><br />"
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set Command.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set Command = Nothing
    
Connection.Close
%><hr />
<a href="?">SHOW ALL</a><hr />
<form method="post" action="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>">
Name : <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="255" /> <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

*As a last remark:*

When you need to apply html encoding to strings fetched from the database, you shouldn't use Server.HTMLEncode anymore due to Response.Codepage is 1252 on server-side and since Server.HTMLEncode is dependent context codepage this will cause gibberish outputs. 
So you'll need to write your own html encoder to handle the case.

```vb
Function MyOwnHTMLEncode(ByVal str)
    str = Replace(str, "&", "&amp;")
    str = Replace(str, "<", "&lt;")
    str = Replace(str, ">", "&gt;")
    str = Replace(str, """", "&quot;")
    MyOwnHTMLEncode = str
End Function
'Response.Write MyOwnHTMLEncode(rs("myfield").value)
```

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion, but now I have a problem with hard-coded Slovenian letters. Data from MySQL is ok now, but hard-coded text does not show correctly: http://slotenis.si/test.asp

Comment: @gdolenc ASP's Response Stream is BOM sensitive. Try to save your files `ANSI as UTF-8 Encoded` ie `UTF-8 without BOM`. In English Notepad++ through `Encode > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`

Comment: Actually the hard-coded data is correct, as long as it is really hard-coded, that menas written as HTML. If I use ASP/VBscript command Response.Write ..., than Slovenian characters are not printed ok. Anyway, this is solved now. But there is another problem. How to INSERT data in MySQL with čšžČŠŽ? I have problems with č, which becommes c in db, and Č becommes C.

Comment: @gdolenc I have no any encoding problems including INSERT and Response.Write's. Everything is just fine for me. Here is another test page : http://aspfiddle.com/gdolenc2.asp can download the source btw. May have missed out something.

Comment: Perfect. Now it works. You are a genius. Finally found a guy who really knows about encoding issues and how to solve them. Very helpful and thank god that such great people still exist on earth. To summarize for those of you who will be looking for solution: 1. All your files have to be UTF-8 encode without BOM!!! 2. Add SET NAMES UTF8 to connection string like this: connectstr = "Driver … ";stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8';". 3. Just because of FireFox, you have to add Response.Charset = "utf-8" at the top of every processing script, which inserts data into db. And that’s about it.

Comment: So much miss-information here. You should never mix `Response.Charset` and `Response.CodePage` or you will end up with an encoding mismatch.

Comment: @Lankymart did you read the question? this is not information just a workaround for Slovenian & MyODBC 3.51 (non-unicode driver). `GoDaddy is not supporting MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver, which could be a solution.`

Comment: Yeah I read the question but explain to me how telling the browser to decode `UTF-8` but sending it `Windows-1252` works? Maybe I'm miss understanding how the hack works, you don't seem to explain why you do that. Even Microsoft [advise against it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525304%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - *"The CharsetName of `Response.Charset` must match the code page value or mixed characters are displayed in the browser."*

Comment: adding `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" ... >` in the form declaration is what worked for me