# Reading Thai characters from MySQL using ASP

Tags: mysql, utf-8, asp-classic

I have Thai characters in MySQL but they don't transfer to my ASP generated web page correctly. I've linked to screen shots of the crucial factors showing the data is OK in the table but not on the website as seen in the last screen shot. Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

http://www.transum.com/Temp/ThaiScript.PNG

- The first two pictures are from phpMyAdmin
- The third picture is the header of my webpage.
- The fourth picture shows what appears on the webpage.

I have already added the UTF-8 instruction to the connection:

```
Conn.execute ("SET NAMES utf8")
SQL = "select * from Phrases WHERE Checked = TRUE Order by English ASC"
set RSrecord = Conn.execute (SQL)
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Did you put the values into the database using the same encoding as when you read? Like, Form's are UTF-8, Data UTF-8, Connection on insert is UTF-8...

Comment: Dan, I exported the values from an Access database to create the MySQL table. I think it's all UTF-8

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to MySql.  If you're using MyODBC 3.51 then I recommend you upgrade to MyODBC 5.1 if you can.  The only difference between these two pages is that the second one uses the later driver - http://clubdanceholidays.co.uk/aboutusru.asp , http://clubdanceholidays.co.uk/aboutusru51.asp

Comment: @John Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I am using MyODBC 3.51. I tried changing it to 5.1 but got an error message. I logged into my host (GoDaddy) to find the version of MySQL and it turned out to be 5.0. I tried 'MySQL ODBC 5.0 Driver' but again got an error message.

Comment: MyODBC isn't the database itself, it's the driver which asp uses to connect to it.  You clearly have v3.51 of the driver installed and not v5.1, so you will need to use the 3.51 connection string unless you can get GoDaddy to upgrade to the newer version (or find another host - I know that Storm Internet use v5.1).  This question covered the same sort of issues, and someone came up with a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269039/classic-asp-mysql-or-odbc-utf8-encoding/18289431#18289431

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your source, my first question (or suggestion) is whether you are HTML encoding your output?

```
Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(RSrecord.Fields("Thai_Script"))
```

If this doesn't work for you, can you show a bit more code?

Comment: Thanks Polly. I tried (see below) but it didn't solve the problem. Which particular part of the code do you want to see?

Comment: `Conn.execute ("SET NAMES utf8")
SQL = "select * from Phrases WHERE Checked = TRUE Order by English ASC"
set RSrecord = Conn.execute (SQL)
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
while not RSrecord.BOF and not RSrecord.EOF
 Thai = Server.HTMLEncode(RSrecord.Fields("Thai_Script"))
 Response.write ("<tr><td>" & RSrecord("English") & "</td><td>" & Thai & "</td></tr>")
 RSrecord.Movenext
Wend
Set RSrecord = Nothing
Conn.close`

Comment: Can you just put something like `Server.HTMLEncode("ฏปฏัก")` in your code and verify that it can output correctly? Your HTML output should end up as `&#3599;&#3611;&#3599;&#3633;&#3585;`

Comment: Thanks @Polly  Yes, I tried that and did indeed get &#3599;&#3611;&#3599;&#3633;&#3585;

Comment: Assuming that the data is all stored correctly in the database, which it does seem to be, and assuming that doing the above test rendered the Thai characters correctly, that would indicate to me that the issue is with the database driver. You've basically excluded all other layers of the request. I'd recommend updating it to the latest version, if it isn't already. Out of interest, could you post some examples of Thai data from the database and the HTML encoded output that it currently outputs for it? It might offer some clues.

Comment: Thanks again @Polly. I'm getting "à¹€à¸„à¸£à¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¸‡à¸šà¸´à¸™" as can be seen here: http://www.transum.com/Thai/Number_Select.asp

Comment: Could you post the original Thai (direct from the db) for one or two of them for me to compare to the output?

Comment: Here is the Thai word for airplane: เครื่องบิน

Comment: I can't see any obvious pattern. My only further suggestions are to update your database driver if possible, or if there is no way around the driver a fairly horrible workaround would be to add another `varchar` column to your database table and calculate the HTML encoded version of the Thai words (ie, `เครื่องบิน` posted above = `&#3648;&#3588;&#3619;&#3639;&#3656;&#3629;&#3591;&#3610;&#3636;&#3609;`) directly into the field. That could then be read from the database and written directly to the page (not encoding it again, of course). Sorry I can't offer a better solution!

Comment: Looking at the nunber_select.asp page link you posted, you aren't getting lots of question marks, you're getting utf-8 characters displayed as if they're iso-8859-1.  Is your page actually saved as utf-8.  You can test this by opening it in notepad and selecting "save as" from the File menu.  If ANSI encoding is selected then change it to utf-8 and save

Comment: Actually, the solution might be the exact opposite - ie changing from utf-8 to ANSI with a text editor.  The utf-8 instructions you've applied to your recordset object look like a way to get an ANSI page to display utf-8 characters.  Anyway, you can experiment

Comment: @John Hi. It did make a difference but it did not solve the problem. Here's the page saved as UTF-8 http://www.transum.com/Thai/Number_Select2.asp compared to the one saved as ANSI http://www.transum.com/Thai/Number_Select.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked this one out. First of all I should repeat that if you can possibly install MyODBC v5.1 then do so and don't bother trying to configure for 3.51.  Unfortunately it would appear that the older driver is all that a certain large and well known web host seems to offer.

Here's a link to a version of my Russian Cyrillic page.  It uses the old driver, (MyODBC 3.51)

http://clubdanceholidays.co.uk/aboutusruansi.asp

The crucial points to note are:

1) In the first line:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252" LCID="2057" %>
```

Use 1252 rather than 65001 as your codepage value - I realise just how counterintuitive this is, but in this specific situation it works.

2) Your line

```
Conn.execute ("SET NAMES utf8")
```

Adding this query immediately before the query to populate my recordset was the missing piece of the jigsaw for me.

3) The Charset meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This should definitely be UTF-8.  Essentially we're telling the server that it's a Windows-1252 page and the browser that it's a UTF-8 page.

4) What kind of encoding to use when you save the file

This is a little more complicated.  If you're using Notepad then you need to use ANSI.  The UTF-8 option is actually UTF-8 + BOM, which seems to create a conflict with the codepage definition in point 1.  The problem with ANSI comes if you need to hardcode any non-western characters into your page - you couldn't insert them as they are, you would need to manually encode them first, eg for เครื่องบิน you would need to insert à¹€à¸„à¸£à¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¸‡à¸šà¸´à¸™

If you have a more powerful editor than Notepad,  (I use Editplus - http://www.editplus.com/ - it's not free but it's quite cheap) you may find two UTF-8 options.  Choose the one without BOM.

Comment: Just moved to a new server and was again having this problem until I implemented the suggestion above... and it worked. Thank you so much. Sorry I can't vote this answer up but my 'reputation' is not high enough. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you got there.  I learned a bit myself in answering this question